# python downloading multiple urls(pdf, html, ppt, doc) on a single core. how to efficiently download?

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I am building an app that downloads average html pages, pdfs, ppt, docs from urls. Since this is for NLP, I only care about the text and don't care about html tags. For pdfs, ppt, docs, I can't ignore all the extra fluff, but at least for html pages I can.

here is a function that I wrote:

```
def saveFiles(name,url,sizeLim,ftype):

    req = requests.head(url)
    #check file size first
    content_size=req.headers["content-length"]
    #file is too large, dont waste time download this
    if content_size>sizeLim:
        return None
    req = requests.get(url)

    with open(name+"."+ftype,"wb") as dfile:
        dfile.write(req.content)
    ...
```

This works, but all it does is limit download of files that are too big. Is there anything I can do? How do I download text only html pages? Are there optimizations that can occur with pdf, ppt, docs?

Comment: I doubt most servers will offer you "text only" versions of content. You'll need to download the full files and process them locally. What comes to speeding up downloads, the most important thing would be to download multiple things concurrently instead of one by one.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen whats the golden standard nowadays to download multiple things? I

Comment: Nowadays? I like `asyncio` in Python 3.5.

Comment: Using `gevent` to download concurrently.